# Easy way to edit object thumbnails in cities skylines?

Tags: mods, cities-skylines, steam-workshop

Does anyone know an easy way to change workshop objects' default thumbnail icons in cities skylines?

I love the game but I am fed up searching the right object in a panel containing a dozend or more of the ugly white-bricked default icons because the modders forgot to create one for their objects.
I figured out that I can load an object into the asset editor and add an icon/thumbnail and then save the object as a new (personal/private?) object and delete the original afterwards - but I don't think that is a good approach (I will have to Provide Updates myself...?)

I wonder if there is a better and easy way to get at least a minimum of comfort back by change / add a thumbnail for the objects that are missing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mod called [Improved Asset Icons](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=508195208) that can help with this problem. Basically, if there's no icon set for an asset, it looks if there is a preview image on the Workshop and uses that. From the description:

- Custom assets that do not have icons, but do have Steam Workshop
  previews will use the Workshop preview as their icon, instead of the
  default box icon.
- Custom assets with their own icons that use the    default dark-blue
  focused icon will have their focused icon re-tinted to fit better
  with the built-in assets.
- Custom assets that do not have a tooltip image but do have
  Steam Workshop previews will use the Workshop preview as their
  tooltip image.

Comment: JMR I just yesterday stumbled about this thing and tried it. It does not provide a picture for all objects BUT FOR MOST of them, so yes, this is the best way to go for me and maybe the most useful mod available :)